# Is someone able to explain this potential divider circuit in detail?

Tags: voltage, resistors, voltage-divider

This schematic is part of a practical that we will later solder on to a PCB.

It is a potential divider, but I have never seen one like this. There are multiple test points on the circuit to measure voltage using a multimeter.

How would I calculate the voltage between these points, and if possible could you explain the circuit to me? I assume that between TP2 and TP3, 5V will be read, and then on TP2 and TP4 it would be 4.54V? But I am not sure on other combinations, e.g TP1 and TP4.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: You have to calculate the equivalent top resistor (R1) and bottom resistor (R2) of the equivalent voltage divider.

Comment: All of those "JP" parts are optional - they may, or may not, be fitted. In order to try to calculate the voltage at any point in that circuit, you need to know which JP's are fitted (shorted) and which are not (open). Once you know that it's a relatively simple bunch of parallel resistor / voltage-divider calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JP1, 3, 5, 7, and 9 are there to connect the "top" of the individual dividers to either 5V or another voltage applied at TP2, 5, etc.  Same deal with JP2, 4, etc and TP3, 6, 9, etc.  JP11, 12, 13, and 14 can be used to isolate each divider from each other or possibly connect dividers in parallel to e.g. get 5 kohm from paralleling two 10k resistors.  If you are using this circuit for a lab or something later, I'm sure whatever procedure you're using will put it through its paces.

Comment: all of the jumps in the middle will be soldered together. This would mean I could calculate tp2 to tp7, how do I calculate that?

Comment: Find the parallel combination of all the "top" resistors together and all the "bottom" resistors together and you will end up with a single two-resistor voltage divider which I assume you already know how to solve or will learn from whichever course this is for.

Comment: I seem to be getting a negative value when I do that?

Comment: The combination of 1000ohm and 2200 ohm would give 687.5, and the combination of two 10k gives 5000 ohm meaning the values would be negative?

Comment: You've correctly calculated the top resistor (connected to 5V) to be 687.5 and the bottom (connected to ground) to be 5000. Those resistors are connected together so in the middle you'd expect some voltage between 0 and 5V. Since 687.5 is smaller than 5000 that voltage will be closer to 5V than 0 but certainly not negative.